# How to create a DateInterval from a time string

Tags: php, dateinterval

If I have a time format string like "14:30:00" ("hours:minutes:seconds"), how do I get a DateInterval from the string?

I can get a DateTime:

```
$datetime= DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i:s","14:30:00");
```

But I need to add it to another DateTime object, and date_add needs a DateInterval.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want an interval that is 14 hours and 30 minutes, simply use the constructor...

```
$interval = new DateInterval('PT14H30M');
```

To break it down...

- `P` - all interval spec strings must start with `P` (for *Period*). We aren't using any period intervals though so on to...
- `T` - this starts the *Time* spec
- `14H` - 14 hours
- `30M` - 30 minutes

If you *must* use the string *14:30:00*, I'd parse it with `sscanf` and use the parts...

```
list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = sscanf('14:30:00', '%d:%d:%d');
$interval = new DateInterval(sprintf('PT%dH%dM%dS', $hours, $minutes, $seconds));
```

Comment: Love the sscanf approach! Thanks

Comment: Yes, the sscanf approach is brilliant for times pulled out of a database. This functionality is really missing from the DateTime library.

Comment: if you love this list/sscanf combo, you gotta love python :)

Comment: Why do you use `list` when you can do this: **`sscanf($mTime, '%d:%d:%d', $h,$m,$s);`**?