# PHP add time to date

Tags: php, date, time

I have a php time "09:00" that I want to set as the time for a date.

```
$date="2016-08-21 00:00:00.000000";
$time="09:00";
```

So ideally:

```
$datetime=$date+$time;//<----------what is the function for this
echo $datetime;
```

gives "2016-08-21 09:00:00.000000"

or

```
$date="2016-08-21 00:00:00.000000";
$time="17:30";
```

then

```
$datetime=$date+$time;//<----------what is the function for this
echo $datetime;
```

gives "2016-08-21 17:30:00.000000".
A seemingly simple requirement I cannot find a solution to.

Comment: [hint](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php)

Comment: Marks hint was the function date_time_set which takes integers - I have a php time object eg "09:00" do I really need to convert to string and parse it ???

Comment: You do realise that you can easily split `09:00` into an array of integers by exploding on `:`?

Comment: `$date="2016-08-21 00:00:00.000000"; $time="09:00"; $dto = new DateTime($date); list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $time); $dto->setTime($hours, $minutes);` [Demo](https://3v4l.org/BG5EC)

Comment: Mark - this was indeed the only simplest way I can see - add it as an answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pending Mark adding an answer this was what I had but it seems clumsy - I hoped there was a better way:

```
 $timebits = explode(":", $timepart);
 $now->setTime($timebits[0], $timebits[1], $timebits[2]);
```

Comment: the source code in the answer is incomplete. Define $now. Plus it relies on time in format HH:mm:ss

Comment: perhaps @AlexPandrea should read the question and write a constructive comment instead of trolling and downvoting - clearly requiring HH:mm:ss and also the PHP doc for 'setTime' which clearly refers to a DateTime object. Labelling the variable 'now' I think is self explanatory.

Comment: no intention to troll but since you answered your question and marked the answer as the accepted one, my opinion is that the solution quality and explanation could be better - as StackOverflow aims to high(er) quality answers. But you're right as well - nor I, nor other have produced better answers. It's a subjective view.

Comment: @AlexPandrea to be in a position to downvote you should also be in a position to either provide a 'better quality answer' that you speak of or correctly dispute my response to your initial comment. I think leaving downvote as is with no further constructive information, other than the contradiction that I am right but also being right is a subjective view does not increase StackOverflow quality in anyway whatsoever and also reflects badly on yourself.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
<?php
  $date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
  $date->add(new DateInterval('PT10H30S'));
  echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
 ?>
```

Comment: So I need to parse the php time string for "09:00" - I hoped to avoid this as not efficient if there was a datetime function instead of string parsing

Comment: No thats complete creation - I have the date already, I want to set the time part

Comment: there is no showing what to do with $time as a variable hence not perfect my friend

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21742329/how-to-create-a-dateinterval-from-a-time-string. This approach is better, just need to create DateInterval string by this pattern. Upvote by me.

Comment: Not a solution, I stated 2 variables not a construct, hence now downvoting and setting my solution as the answer unless Mark formally submits his comment as an answer